# Escape Regex.replace() replacement string in VB.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace

I want to use `Regex.replace(input As String, pattern As String, replacement As String)` in VB.net. The replacement string can contain substitutions of the form `$1` or `${test}`.

I need to call this with replacements I have no control over. So I'd like to escape all substitutions in my replacement strings. Java has `Matcher.quoteReplacement()` to do exactly that job.

- Is there a `Regex.quoteReplacement(replacement As String) As String` or similar that escapes all substitutions in the given string?
- Can I turn substitutions off?
- Is there some alternative I could use instead?

---

- [MSDN for Regex.replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taz3ak2f(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MSDN for substitutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx)
- [JavaDoc for Matcher.quoteReplacement()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution that works in simple cases is:

```
Function quoteReplacement(text As String) As String
    Return Regex.Replace(text, "\$", "$$$$")
End Function
```

But I'm not at all sure that works in all corner cases there might be.